# Pytorch - Use a UNet to perform Image Deblurring/Image Reconstruction

Tags: python, image, image-processing, deep-learning, pytorch

Currently, I'm working with a dataset where I have two kinds of images: "sharp version" of the image and "blurry version" of the same images, where a blur was added synthetically. My goal is to train a model that takes the blurry version of the images in and tries to deblur the image as much as it can so that the "deblurred image" is closer to the sharp version. In the literature, the UNet architecture seemed to be a model with good results. Additionally, I can use a pre-trained U-Net via Pytorch (https://pytorch.org/hub/mateuszbuda_brain-segmentation-pytorch_unet/).

My problem is now: When I train this pre-trained U-Net with my images and then try it on my test set, I get the following output:

[image: Output]

The original image:

[image: Original]

I know that this pre-trained model is usually used for biomedical image segmentation but I'm rather confused about how I have to modify the model to use it for an Image Deblurring/Reconstruction task. Does anyone have any advice on how to do this?

I would appreciate any feedback :)

Answer (score 1):

The U-net you're using is for segmentation (classification of each pixels of the image) whereas you're trying to denoise the image (getting your image "sharper"/remove noise). It explains the results you got.

To get what you want you need and as DerekG said, you first need to modify the number of channels of the output. By modify it, you can't load all the pretrained model. You will have to copy parameters by parameters until the last one.

As the last layer is initialized randomly, you can retrained the model with your training set. You can freeze or not the pretrained parts.

Also, I'm not sure what your new dataset is but if it's really not related to biomedical images you should retrain your network from scratch (transfer learning shouldn't be done in these cases), maybe even change the encoder-decoder network.

Answer (score 0):

From the included link:

```
import torch
model = torch.hub.load('mateuszbuda/brain-segmentation-pytorch', 'unet',
    in_channels=3, out_channels=1, init_features=32, pretrained=True)
```

The model you define has a single output channel, resulting in a grayscale image output. You need 3 output channels for an RGB image.

Comment: Thank you so much for your input! When I changed the argument 'out_channels' to 3, unfortunately I receive the following error message: RuntimeError: Error(s) in loading state_dict for UNet:
 size mismatch for conv.weight: copying a param with shape torch.Size([1, 32, 1, 1]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([3, 32, 1, 1]).
 size mismatch for conv.bias: copying a param with shape torch.Size([1]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([3]).

Comment: But in regards to my initial result: I did change the output_channels in the last Conv2d-layer from 1 to 3 which led to the result in the question

Comment: Yeah, that is expected. This is because the saved file you are trying to load assumes that the model has a different structure than it has in your case. You could try to find a different pretrained model file (perhaps here https://github.com/qubvel/segmentation_models.pytorch), or you can modify the state_dict so that it has the same parameter sizes as the model (initialize the new parameters with random weights and learn them during training).